# invertible elements of polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

what is invertible elements of polynomial ring $k[x_1,...,x_n]$  ? for case  $n=1$ we have $k[x_1]$ and $$
p(x)=a_{0}+a_{1} x+\ldots a_{n} x^{n}
$$
then $p(x)$ is invertible element such that $a_{0}$ is a unit in $R,$ and the remaining coefficients $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n}$ are nilpotent elements. ( $k$ is a field)

Comment: How many nilpotents does a field have?

Answer (score 0):

If $k$ is a field then for nonzero polynomials in $k[x_1]$, say $p$ and $q$ You have
$$\deg(pq)=\deg(p)+\deg(q)$$
and since $\deg(1)=0$, where $1$ is the constant polynomial with coefficient $1$, You see that the image of $k^*=k\backslash\{0\}$ in $k[x_1]$ is the set of units in $k[x_1].$